# How can be transformed [EventLoopFuture<Type>] into EventLoopFuture<[Type]> in Vapor?

Tags: swift, vapor

I try to transform [EventLoopFuture Type ] into EventLoopFuture<[Type]>.

Code example:

```
struct QuestionDTO2: Content {
  var text: String?
}

func getUserQuestions(req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<[QuestionDTO2]> {
  let a = try req.content.decode(GetUserQuestions.self)
  return Question.query(on: req.db).all().flatMap {qs -> EventLoopFuture<[QuestionDTO2]> in 
    return qs.map {q -> EventLoopFuture<QuestionDTO2> in 
      QuestionDTO2(text: q.text)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```swift
func getUserQuestions(req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<[QuestionDTO2]> {
    Question.query(on: req.db).all().map {
        $0.map { QuestionDTO2(text: $0.text) }
    }
}
```

You just have to replace `flatMap` with `map` cause next code doesn't return `EventLoopFuture`.

Comment: Thanks. It heleped, and in the third line instead of EventLoopFuture<[QuestionDTO2]> only [QuestionDTO2] was needed.

Comment: Yes sir, thanks, I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

So the solution is:

```
return Question.query(on: req.db).all().map { qs -> [QuestionDTO2] in
    return qs.map { q -> QuestionDTO2 in ( 
        QuestionDTO2(text: q.text) 
      )
    }
  }
```

Comment: It's a good idea to add to your answer the reason that the code answers the original question